# Struts2 jsp page opening in a new window instead of content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, struts2

I have a Struts2 application in which the home page is horizontally split into Header, Menu, Content and Footer. On click of the menu, a "navigate" action is invoked via JQuery and Ajax. The menu name is passed as a parameter to the action through the s:url tag. Based on the menu name, the JSP page name is dynamically prepared. However the Ajax response does not get loaded in the Content part of the page but gets redirected to a new page. I am not sure why this is happening. Below are the code snippets.

Menu.jsp

```
<!-- Dynamic Menu Bar -->
<div id="menu" class="divMenu">
    <ul>
        <s:iterator var="parent" value="menuList">
            <li>
                <s:a href="#">
                    <s:property value="#parent.menuDesc" />
                </s:a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <s:iterator var="child" value="#parent.childrenList">
                        <li>
                            <s:url var="urlValue" action="navigate">
                                <s:param name="pageName" value="#child.menuDesc" />
                            </s:url>
                            <s:a method="post" href="%{urlValue}" onclick="menuNavigate(this)">
                                <s:property value="#child.menuDesc" />
                            </s:a>
                        </li>
                    </s:iterator>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </s:iterator>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript Function

```
function menuNavigate(action) {
    alert(action);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : action + ".action",
        datatype: "html",
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response);
            $("#content").html(response);
        },
        error : function(err) {
            $("#content").html(err);
        }
    });
}
```

BTW, I am able to see the response using the alert under the success part of the Ajax call. On clicking OK, the response gets displayed in a new window.

Struts2 XML

```
<action name="navigate" class="com.web.action.home.HomePageAction" method="navigate">
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/${pageName}</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Can you try removing the `method="post"` from `<s:a` ? No matter if it works btw, it's wrong: 1) method is action method, not http method, and 2) action method referenced like this means DMI that is discouraged

Comment: I did not have method="post" in s:a earlier and was trying it out as it was not working. The code got pasted along with it. I will try the prevent default and let you know. Has it got something to do with namespace in the struts.xml. Currently my namespace is / and since I am passing a param with the URL, the browser URL changes as it gets submitted via GET method.

Comment: Namespace has nothing to do with it. You're clicking a link and the browser is doing exactly what you told it to--you need to prevent default or return false or the link will act like any other.

Comment: preventDefault() has worked for me. Thanks for the suggestions. If anyone can add the answer I will upvote and mark it accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I've skimmed the href part. Then `preventDefault()` OR use `javascript:void(0);` (, `#`, etc...) as  href. @AleksandrM should answer, but if he won't, do it yourself, answer your own question. P.S: you can't upvote until you reach 15 of reputation, but it's good that you are already thinking to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an `event.preventDefault()` worked for me. Thanks for all of them who provided their valuable suggestions.